# Ruby: Idiom for "create and increment"

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a concise way to deal with the following situation: Given a variable (in practince, an instance variable in a class, though I don't think this matters here), which is known to be either `nil` or hold some `Integer`. If it is an Integer, the variable should be incremented. If it is nil, it should be initialized with `1`.

These are obvious solutions to this, taking `@counter` as the variable to deal with:

```
# Separate the cases into two statements
@counter ||= 0
@counter += 1
```

or

```
# Separate the cases into one conditional
@counter = @counter ? (@counter + 1) : 1
```

I don't like these solutions because they require to repeat the name of the variable. The following attempt failed:

```
# Does not work
(@counter ||= 0) += 1
```

This can't be done, because the result of the assignment operators is not an lvalue, though the actual error message is a bit obscure. In this case, you get the error _unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting end_.

Is there a good idiom to code my problem, or do I have to stick with one of my clumsy solutions?

Comment: `@counter = @counter.to_i + 1`?

Comment: Nice, but also requires `@counter` to be mentioned twice. Imagine that instead of having a simple variable, we want to deal with `@counter_array[my_function(i,j,k)]` to be incremented in this way.

Comment: @user1934428: And it’s an array, not a hash?

Comment: If it is a `Hash`, you might have `default_proc`. If it’s an instance variable, you might initialize it to zero in the constructor.

Comment: If the index is a calculation, factor it out: `my_function(i, j, k).then { |index| @counter_array[index] ||= 0; @counter_array[index] += 1 }` (or equivalently `index = my_function(i, j, k); @counter_array[index] ||= 0; @counter_array[index] += 1`)

Comment: If you know the size of the array, you can pre-fill it with zeroes. E.g. if you know the index will never reach 20, `@counter_array = Array.new(20, 0)`, and then you don't need the check any more.

Comment: @Amadan : If I know the size, it is possible. If I don't know, or if it is not an array, but a Hash, it is not. Or if it is just a simple variable, as stated in my posting. It is obvious that we can solve this depending on the circumstance in various ways, but these does not relate to the original problem.  I was looking for something similar in spirit as in `C` or `C++`, where you can write something like `(foo[bar()] ||= m) += n`, because assignments return lvalues. I just wondered whether there is some trick in the realm of Ruby, which would have a comparable effect.

Comment: If it's a hash, then as Aleksei said, `Hash.new(0)` and it all just works. But yes, there is no way to get lvalue in Ruby as a result of an expression.

Comment: I think the basic problem is, that the class `Integer` does not have any methods, which actually *change* the value represented by an instance. You can even not monkeypatch the class to define a method `incr!`, which would modify the receiver by incrementing it. With this restrictions, it seems to be impossible to achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: @Amadan : With a Hash, it would work only if you want to have **all** new values to spring out with value 0, which is not what I want to achieve. Incidentally, in my concrete case which triggered the posting, the value happens to be an element in a Hash, and since many of the elements in the Hash are not Integer-valued, it does not make sense to have 0 as a default initializer....

Comment: @user1934428 while your statement about `Integer` are correct there is nothing that keeps you from creating your own class that can implement such a feature and using that as your value. e.g. `(@counter ||= Counter.new).increment!`

Comment: @steenslag : Did you try it? This gives the error message _undefined method 'to_i=' for nil:NilClass_ (in Ruby 2.6.3p62).

Comment: @user1934428: "I think the basic problem is, that the class Integer does not have any methods, which actually change the value represented by an instance." – If this were possible, it would be really, really, really, really bad. Imagine, some library that you use calls `1.inc!`, and then somewhere else in your code, you do `1 + 1` and the result is `4`!!!

Comment: @JörgWMittag : Well, `1` is a literal, and this could(should be protected for a change anyway. In a similar way, you can not do a `'abc'`[0] = 'x'` although you can do a `s='abc'; s[0]='x'`.

Comment: @user1934428: Actually, you *can* do `'abc'[0] = 'x'` just fine. `1` is an `Integer` like any other `Integer`. You said you wanted a way to change the value of an instance of `Integer`. Well, `1` *is* an instance of `Integer`. With your proposed `inc!` method, the following would also happen: `n = 1; n.inc!; 1 + 1 #=> 4`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : `'abc'[0] = 'x'` works only if you don't have `--enable=frozen-string-literal`, otherwise you get a _can't modify frozen String_. In Ruby 3, this is going to be the default behaviour, which makes sense to me. Indeed, if the language where designed to allow an Integer object to be mutable, the language would most likely also freeze Integer literals in the same way, simply to avoid such bizarre bugs which you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is clear:

- A variable is known to hold `nil` or an integer. If `nil` the variable is to be set equal to `1`, else it is to be set equal to its value plus `1`.
- What is the best way to implement this in Ruby?

First, two points.

- The question states, "If it is nil, it should be initialized with `1`.". This contradicts the statement that the variable is known to be `nil` or an integer, meaning that it has already been initialized, or more accurately, *defined*. In the case of an instance variable, this distinction is irrelevant as Ruby initializes undefined instance variables to `nil` when they are referenced as [rvalues](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch04s05.html). It's an important distinction for local variables, however, as an exception is raised when an undefined local variable is referenced as an rvalue.
- The comments largely address situations where the variable holds an object other than `nil` or an `integer`. They are therefore irrelevant. If the OP wishes to broaden the question to allow the variable to hold objects other than `nil` or an integer (an array or hash, for example), a separate question should be asked.

What criteria should be used in deciding what code is best? Of the various possibilities that have been mentioned, I do not see important differences in efficiency. Assuming that to be the case, or that relative efficiency is not important in the application, we are left with readability (and by extension, maintainability) as the sole criterion. If `x` equals `nil` or an integer, or is an undefined instance variable, perhaps the clearest code is the following:

```
x = 0 if x.nil?
x += 1
```

or

```
x = x.nil? ? 1 : x+1
```

Ever-so-slightly less readable:

```
x = (x || 0) + 1
```

and one step behind that:

```
x = x.to_i + 1
```

which requires the reader to know that `nil.to_i #=> 0`.

The OP may regard these solutions as "clumsy", but I think they are all beautiful.

Can an expression be written that references `x` but once? I can't think of a way and one has not been suggested in the comments, so if there is a way (doubtful, I believe) it probably would not meet the test for readability.

Consider now the case where the local variable `x` may not have been defined. In that case we might write:

```
x = (defined?(x) ? (x || 0) : 0) + 1
```

[defined?](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/keywords_rdoc.html) is a Ruby keyword.

Comment: @CarySwoeveland : Actually, the variable is definied, either because it really is an variable explicitly initialized to nil, or because it comes from the hash which is indexted by a non existing key (`myHash[:new_key]`), and the goal is that if the key does not exist yet, the hash element should be initialized, otherwise incremented. Also, from the context I know that when the variable is non-nil, it must be an Integer.

Comment: in the case of non existing hash key I'd rather use hash proc to ensure default value to 0, then add 1
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye : Not a good idea, because this would then assign 0 to **every** new Hash element automatically, not just to those which are supposed to hold an integer value.